# How to properly provide data using parentheses

Tags: grammar

> The expected number of Roma visits Americans made was highest, at 80 thousand, followed by about 50 thousand (Canadians) and 20 thousand (Mexicans).

Here I'm reporting the numbers of visits to Roma expected to be made by Americans, Canadians, and Mexicans. Am I using the parentheses correctly? If not, please recommend some ways to correct the sentence with minimum alteration to it.

P.S. I mostly wonder if I should add "by" before Canadians and Mexicans, but I might have made other mistakes without even noticing them.

[image]

Comment: Simple, minimal change: remove the brackets.   Alos "Roma" is Italian, the English word is Rome (unless you are talking about the football club)

Comment: In the chart I was given it is "Roma"; should I change it to Rome then?

Comment: Actually, the question should be if Roma is acceptable when it's what the chart says.

Comment: As for the bracket removal, I just commented on it below Jay's answer.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you should probably follow the chart.  The phrasing is odd "expected visits" sounds like something in the future, but you use a past tense.  I suppose this might be some technical statistical use of "expected". But however you phrase your description, you probably don't want to use brackets.

Comment: BTW this is probably the chart. It's not a genuine IELTS resource.  They may be incompetent at maths, but they are not going to spell the name of the capital city of Spain wrong  https://essayforum.com/writing/expected-city-visits-country-origin-90014/

Answer (score 4):

Remove the parentheses. There is nothing parenthetical about the place of origin. Just say, "... followed by 50 thousand Canadians and 20 thousand Mexicans".

You would only need parentheses if you were including some "side" information. Like "... followed by 50 thousand Canadians (most of them from Quebec) ..."

Here's a simple rule: Try removing everything inside the parentheses and see if the sentence still makes sense. If not, you generally should not include the parentheses. (There may be exceptions to this but I think it's a good general rule.)

By the way, ditto James K. If you're referring to the capital of Italy, then if you are writing in English you should use the English name, Rome, not the Italian name, Roma. If you're talking about some other place or thing called "Roma", ignore this comment. In general, you should only include a word that is not from the same language as the bulk of your text if there is no available word in that language, if you are talking about the word itself ("this is what the Greeks call ..."), or if you are quoting someone.

Comment: I think it would be different without the parentheses. 80 thousand was the number of __visits__ made by Americans. One American might make several visits, therefore there might be fewer than 80 thousand Americans visiting Rome. But if I removed the parentheses, it would no longer be about the number of visits, but about the number of visitors.

Comment: I'd like to think that 50 thousand visits equals 50 thousand visitors. I mean it'd be better for me if the examiner didn't mind the difference I mentioned because I would have more room to paraphrase the sentence for my exam. I'm not sure if it's acceptable though.

Comment: @KenAdams With the parentheses, it is not at all clear that you mean visits rather than visitors. There is no convention in English that "20,000 Canadians" means 20,000 people from Canada but "20,000 (Canadians)" means 20,000 something else done by an unspecified number of Canadians. If you want to clarify this distinction, you have to use words, not just punctuation. You could, for example, say, "20,000 visits by Canadians". You can't just invent a new notation, not explain it, and expect readers to understand what you mean.

Comment: Absolutely. This is **correct**. Numbers plus a nationality in an example like this would not use parentheses. And, of course, Rome because Roma are Roma gypsies or the Romani people.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you could remove the parentheses:

> The number of Roma visits Americans made was highest, at 80 thousand, followed by about 50 thousand Canadians and 20 thousand Mexicans.

or you could swap things around:

> The  number of Americans visiting Rome was highest (80,000), followed by Canadians (50,000) and Mexicans (20,000).

P.S. As others have remarked, **expected...made** doesn't work. "are expected to make" if it's a projected number.

Comment: And since we don't have the chart, I'm not worrying about the difference between visitors and visits -- just focusing on how parentheses are typically used in contexts like this one.   The number usually goes inside them, not the category.

Comment: P.S. Some style guides would have you spell out 80, 50, and 20 in the version not using parentheses, eighty thousand, fifty thousand, twenty thousand, rather than mix number and word.